# JqxGrid - Load on search or filter

Tags: javascript, angular, jqxgrid, jqwidget

Is there a way in JqxGrid to load data on filtering.

Example:
 Suppose there is a Column of First Names,

`FIRSTNAMES
 Anto
 Antony
 Bart`

and I enter, say, `Ro`, in the filter. Now, is there way to make an server call and load the more rows based on the call result? 
For instance can I add a `Rob` or `Roy`, if found.

Comment: Yes. It is possible with dataAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On checking the docs and the JQWidgets forum, I guess there is no way to to this. If anyone ever wants such a functionality then you must use the Grid toolbar and implement your own custom filter/search.